# Gutenberg theme development: how to add "headers" option under styles > colors > elements?

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

[image]

I'm not sure if this is even possible as I'm still learning about Gutenberg full site editing theme development. I've done my best to research this and read over the documentation before asking this question.

In the theme editor using a Gutenberg block theme, it's possible to set the colors for Background, Text, & Links (see screenshot). Is there a way to add "Headers" to this section so that header colors can be controlled across the theme as well?